# How to make dropdown in the Google sheet for day, month and year in separate column

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have tried the list of items approach but stuck in the year.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to select a valid date, you need to set your *Criteria* to "Date", not to a list of items.

See the screenshot below:
[image: date validation]
Otherwise there is no clean way of adding the date validation. You can of course choose month, day and year separately from a dropdown, but not very clear why you'd want it that way as then you will need to concat those entries in a new cell.

Comment: for year you can use =year(now())+0,=year(now())+1 ....,year(now())+n

Comment: or you can use formula if without drop down list just for validation purpose